# Textbooks on Algorithmic Number Theory

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-number-theory, textbook-recommendation

I am looking for a good textbook suitable for graduate or advanced undergraduate students who want to explore algorithmic number theory. Specifically, algorithms for  primality testing, and factoring composite numbers. Can anyone suggest a good text book for this purpose? Thank you in advance.

Comment: this looks like what you'd want: http://www.amazon.com/Algorithmic-Number-Theory-Cryptography-Mathematical/dp/0521808545


This 2008 text provides a comprehensive introduction to algorithmic number theory for beginning graduate students, written by the leading experts in the field. It includes several articles that cover the essential topics in this area, and in addition, there are contributions pointing in broader directions, including cryptography, computational class field theory, zeta functions and L-series, discrete logarithm algorithms, and quantum computing.


Comment: Henri Cohen's books ?

Comment: Definitely Henri Cohen's "A course in computational algebraic number theory" is the best place to start. At a lower level David M. Bressoud "Factorization and Primality Testing" is a nice introduction.

Comment: What do you mean by "explore". Should they learn the subject seriously or just get a bit of a vague idea. For the former I strongly endorse the suggestion of Henri Cohen's book "A course in computational algebraic number theory" (while it says 'algebraic' in the title also classical primetesting algos that have not much to do with alg. numb. theory are covered).  For the latter with some guidance it could also work well; but then I think one should not read it in linear order. 

Comment: Two texts that would support such study, if not quite graduate level, are Hans Riesel's book on factorization and primality testing, and Crandall and Pomerance's book focusing on prime numbers.  Mastering the contents of both books puts you well on the road to such study. Gerhard "Might Remember The Titles Someday" Paseman, 2013.06.09

Comment: You may find some suitable titles on this page   http://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/~duje/literatura.html#PFP 

Comment: William Stein has a book about doing number theory with SAGE.